# Resharper not highlights unused private variables

Tags: c#, resharper

I noticed that Resharper not highlights unused private variables. [In the provided screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2L0Z.png) I set "Dead Code" color to magenta and create some variables. Resharper highlights only public variables.
Is it possible to highlight also private variables?

Thanks

Comment: They all have "..." on them. Press alt+enter on one of them and follow the menu - you should be about to change the severity to something like warning or suggestion, at which point it might show as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, severity for non-used fields by default defined as Warning for private fields.

Comment: Which options are available in the "alt+enter" menu on the private fields?

Comment: @IvanSerduk only convert to _public/internal/protected_ , _encapsulate field_ , _can be null_ , _not null_ . Thats all

[Provide screen as proof](https://prnt.sc/12jc1w1)

Comment: @BobOruel please submit a support request here https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/ for further investigation. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderKurakin [Done](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010661419-Resharper-does-not-highlights-unused-private-variables)

Thanks